# Copy a column value and paste it in another sheet based on the number of times mentioned in the previous sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values in Column A from sheet "Volunteer List" and paste it in sheet "Individual Contacts" on column G. The number of times the value from column A on Volunteer List needs to pasted is on Column D in the same sheet.[Volunteer List[Individual Contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dya81.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r571G.jpg)

I have the below code that copies and pastes based on the values in column D, however, it gets pasted on each column, ex. first value on G, the next on H and so on. Instead, I need it to paste in the same column G but to the row below and keep going until the number of times for each name in column A of [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcrHV.jpg)Volunteer List.

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

Dim StartRow As Byte
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim limitRow As Integer

Sheets("Volunteer List").Activate
StartRow = 2
LastRow = Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count


For i = StartRow To LastRow
If Sheets("Volunteer List").Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
cnt = Sheets("Volunteer List").Range("D" & i).Value
limitRow = cnt + 6
Sheets("Individual Contacts").Activate
For ii = 7 To limitRow
Cells(i, ii) = Sheets("Volunteer List").Range("A" & i).Value
Next ii
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste()

    Dim c As Range, num As Long, cDest As Range
    
    'starting points...
    Set c = Worksheets("Volunteer List").Range("A2")
    Set cDest = Worksheets("Individual Contacts").Range("G2")
    
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0                'while have source data
        num = c.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value 'how many replicates
        cDest.Resize(num).Value = c.Value    'fill values
        Set c = c.Offset(1)                  'next source row
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(num)        'next destination
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up your code a bit and gave some comments to what I added so it's easier to follow.
What I did was give all the rows that need the volunteer's name the name at once, no need to loop there.
Then it's just a matter of jumping forward to the next empty or end-row in your Individual Contacts.

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
    Dim StartRow As Long 'not sure why you'd declare it as a Byte
    Dim LastRow As Long, lRowCont As Long, lRowContGive As Long
    Dim i As Long, nameVol As String
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim wsVol As Worksheet, wsCont As Worksheet
    
    Set wsVol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Volunteer List") 'makes it easier to use them later
    Set wsCont = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Individual Contacts")
    StartRow = 2
    LastRow = wsVol.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    With wsCont
        lRowCont = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'to check how far you need to fill
        lRowContGive = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'in case there were already volunteers given to contacts
        For i = StartRow To LastRow
            nameVol = wsVol.Range("A" & i).Value
            If nameVol <> "" Then
                cnt = wsVol.Range("D" & i).Value
                If lRowContGive + cnt >= lRowCont Then 'don't need to fill further than last row
                    .Range("B" & lRowContGive + 1 & ":B" & lRowCont) = nameVol
                    MsgBox "All done"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    .Range("B" & lRowContGive + 1).Resize(cnt) = nameVol 'give the name at once
                    lRowContGive = lRowContGive + cnt 'for next iteration
                End If
            End If
        Next i
     End With
End Sub
```

Hope it's clear :)